# Why aren't these CSS nth-child selectors working as expected?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Why aren't the 1st, 2nd,3rd, 4th items being styled with `background-color`s as expected?

Please see code snippet:

```css
.list-container.animated .ui.button.bubble:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
}

.list-container.animated .ui.button.bubble:nth-child(2) {
  background: green;
}

.list-container.animated .ui.button.bubble:nth-child(3) {
  background: yellow;
}

.list-container.animated .ui.button.bubble:nth-child(4) {
  background: pink;
}

button {
  outline: none;
  border:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-container animated">
   <form>
      <label>
         <div class="ui button bubble medium">Item 1</div>
      </label>
      <label>
         <div class="ui button bubble medium">Item 2</div>
      </label>
      <label>
         <div class="ui button bubble medium">Item 3</div>
      </label>
      <button class="ui button bubble">Item 4</button>
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: They're all the first child of their parent, except the button which is the fourth.

Comment: did you try searching first? your question or a similar one may have already been answered: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=nth+child+selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look, you are trying to set style on first, second, third (etc.) div with .bubble class. But in every  block there is only one child. So, you need too count labels instead of divs with .bubble.

I advice you to wrap button in a div and give class to this div and give the same class to labels

```
<div class="list-container animated">
       <form>
          <label class="some-class">
             <div class="ui button bubble medium">Item 1</div>
          </label>
          <label class="some-class">
             <div class="ui button bubble medium">Item 2</div>
          </label>
          <label class="some-class">
             <div class="ui button bubble medium">Item 3</div>
          </label>
          <div class="some-class"><button class="ui button bubble">Item 4</button></div>
       </form>
    </div>


.list-container.animated form .some-class:first-child  .ui.button.bubble {
  background: red;
}

.list-container.animated form .some-class:nth-child(2) .ui.button.bubble {
  background: green;
}

.list-container.animated form .some-class:nth-child(3) .ui.button.bubble {
  background: yellow;
}

.list-container.animated form .some-class:last-child .ui.button.bubble {
  background: pink;
}

button {
  outline: none;
  border:none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`nth-child` is for *immediate* children of their parent element - in your case all of the `<div class="ui button bubble medium">` elements are only-child elements of their parent `<label>` element.

The final `<button>` element can be selected with just `button` as it is the only element of that type in the fragment:

Change your rule to this:

```
.list-container.animated label:nth-child(1) .ui.button.bubble {
    background: red;
}

.list-container.animated label:nth-child(2) .ui.button.bubble {
    background: green;
}

.list-container.animated label:nth-child(3) .ui.button.bubble {
    background: yellow;
}

.list-container.animated button {
    background: pink;
}
```

The rules might be easier to follow if you use an explicit heirarchy with the `>` child selector rather than the descendant combinator '' (a space):

```
.list-container.animated > form > label:nth-child(1) > .ui.button.bubble {
    background: red;
}

.list-container.animated > form > label:nth-child(2) > .ui.button.bubble {
    background: green;
}

.list-container.animated > form > label:nth-child(3) > .ui.button.bubble {
    background: yellow;
}

.list-container.animated > form > button {
    background: pink;
}
```

Comment: This is great but notice how `</button>` is not wrapped in a LABEL tag. that's where the above is breaking down...

Comment: @AnApprentice I've amended my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Because the DIVs you are selecting are children of their `label` tag containers/parents, and each of them is a `first-child` therefore (except for the pink `button` at the end, which, as a sibling of the `label`s, is the 4th child of the common parent `.list-container`).

You have to use the n-th-child selectors on the labels instead, lie this:

```css
.list-container.animated label:nth-child(1) .ui.button.bubble {
  background: red;
}

.list-container.animated label:nth-child(2) .ui.button.bubble {
  background: green;
}

.list-container.animated label:nth-child(3) .ui.button.bubble {
  background: yellow;
}

.list-container.animated :nth-child(4) {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-container animated">
  <form>
    <label>
         <div class="ui button bubble medium">Item 1</div>
      </label>
    <label>
         <div class="ui button bubble medium">Item 2</div>
      </label>
    <label>
         <div class="ui button bubble medium">Item 3</div>
      </label>
    <button class="ui button bubble">Item 4</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great but notice how `</button>` is not wrapped in a LABEL tag. that's where the above is breaking down...

Comment: that's why I used different CSS on it. What is breaking down?

Comment: thanks but I need button to be dynamically styled... I'm using color here to keep the question simple. In reality, I'm using LESS like so: 

`.generate-list-container-animation-delays(@n, @i: 0) when (@i =< @n) {

  .list-container.animated .ui.button.bubble:nth-child(@{i}) {
    animation-delay: unit(@initalDelay + (@i * .03), s);
  }

  .generate-list-container-animation-delays(@n, (@i + 1));
}`

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but you can also use this selector for your button: `.list-container.animated :nth-child(4) { ... }` (I also put that into my answer snippet now)

Comment: You could put a class on label and then give the button the same class as the labels? Then you'd use .class_name:nth-child(n) instead of label:nth-child(3)

Comment: @dukedevil294 The labels and the button are siblings, so you can simply use `:nth-child` for them as I did in my edited answer.